# Install FireDAC in Borland Delphi 6

Tags: delphi, firedac

I searched on Google and know that: **FireDAC** component is not available on **Borland Delphi 6** (but available on RAD Studio).

I try to install FireDAC through Component, but I did not find unit/package of FireDac.

Is there any other way, or that is impossible?

Comment: If you *searched on Google and know that FireDAC is not available on Borland Delphi 6*, then you already know that FireDAC is not available on Borland Delphi 6. RAD Studio came long after Delphi 6. You cannot use FireDAC on Delphi 6, and you don't have RAD Studio if you have Delphi 6 because RAD Studio did not exist when Delphi 6 was released. Therefore, you cannot use FireDAC, because you don't have a Delphi version that supports it. If you want to use FireDAC, upgrade your Delphi version to a modern one that includes FireDAC.

Comment: If you're using the correct installer, it should look like it does on this page: http://support.embarcadero.com/article/42970. If the installer does not list Delphi 6, then it cannot be used on it.

Comment: Maybe can not install FireDAC in Borland Delphi 6. Thanks for the answers!

Comment: @RichardAnderson No, not maybe - most definitely!

Comment: @Dave, that applies to FireDAC 8, which supports Delphi 5 up. But I cannot say if you can buy it these days.

Comment: @Victoria: You can't. It belongs to EMBT after their purchase of AnyDAC, and they're not selling it.

Comment: @Ken, I remember that they were selling it separately (when it was already FireDAC).

Comment: @Victoria: If they're selling it, they're selling the current version, which will not work with Delphi 6 (as I and others have already said).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current FireDAC source code depends on generics, which were only introduced into Delphi in Delphi 2009, iirc. See http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Overview_of_Generics

Another problem is that in Delphi 6 string handling is "pre-Unicode" whereas in modern versions of Delphi, strings are by default Unicode.

So, I cannnot see any prospect of you being able to compile FireDAC in D6 even if you have a FireDAC licence, unless you have a copy of the older FireDAC 8 mentioned by @Victoria.

Comment: Actually, FireDAC 8 supports Delphi 5 up. But I cannot say if it's for sale.

Comment: Thanks @Victoria - I've updated my answer to mention your helpful comment.

Comment: Did this answer your q?

Comment: Thanks @MartynA, @Victoria!